# Vue-Multiselect remove event how to get the value and id

Tags: vue.js, vue-multiselect

I am new to VueJs, i am using vue-multiselect and need to get the removed item information.

Eg.: after choosing one or more itens and removing one of them, by clicking on the tag, how can i use the [@remove event](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-events) and get all the information i need like value and id?

Let´s say i have one array like this : `['food', 'farmacy']`

How can i access theses values if they are removed from vuejs-multiselect ?

I write :

```
   <multiselect v-model="value" 
                track-by="code" 
                :options="options" 
                :multiple="true" 
                :taggable="true" 
                placeholder="Choose one category" 
                label="name"
                @remove="toggleUnSelectMarket(value, id)"></multiselect>
```

I just pass value and id as parameters to the `toggleUnSelectLojas` function but did not know how to find the information i need :

```
toggleUnSelectLojas: function(value, id)
  {          

     console.log(' Teste toggleUnSelectMarkets value : ', value)
     console.log(' Teste toggleUnSelectMarkets id : ', id)
  },
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check out this [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/l5lzq06xo9?fontsize=14)

you don't need to pass any parameters on removal the event contains the regarding object. What you than can do is:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <vue-multiselect
      v-bind:options="list"
      v-model="value"
      multiple
      label="id"
      track-by="id"
      @remove="toggleUnSelectMarket"
    ></vue-multiselect>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import vueMultiselect from "vue-multiselect";

export default {
  components: {
    vueMultiselect
  },
  methods: {
    toggleUnSelectMarket({ value, id }) {
      this.toggleUnSelectLojas(value, id);
    },
    toggleUnSelectLojas(value, id) {
      console.log(" Teste toggleUnSelectLojas value : ", value);
      console.log(" Teste toggleUnSelectLojas id : ", id);
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: [],
      list: [
        {
          id: "1",
          value: 2
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          value: 3
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Matt !! "the event contains the regarding object." was the misunderstood piece of information, by  me